# R : 'Path' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: r

I am trying to install the "gtable" R package, but it doesn't work.
Here is the console output.

```
> install.packages("gtable")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
gtable  0.2.0  0.3.0             FALSE

installing the source package ‘gtable’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gtable_0.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 368081 bytes (359 KB)
downloaded 359 KB

'\\path\R\R-3.5.3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gtable’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSw3Prt\downloaded_packages’
```

I see the following folder in the "C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSw3Prt\downloaded_packages" repository.

"gtable_0.3.0.tar.gz"

I had no problems installing other packages.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: This is just a guess, but what does `.libPaths()` return?

Comment: Did you really need the source version? Why not just install the binary?

Comment: @joran .libPaths() returns "\\\\path/R/R-3.5.3/library"

Comment: @MrFlick how would you do that? I just used install.packages. Thank you!

Comment: That does indeed seem like an odd path to be in `.libPaths()`. But I'm not always clear on what's a valid windows file path; maybe someone else can weigh in.

Comment: @joran I successfully installed a lot of packages though, it seems to be a problem about the source file, but I am not sure... Btw, path stands for the beginning of the path. Is "gtable_0.3.0.tar.gz" a compatible source file?

Comment: Well, it seems an unlikely coincidence that your library path appears verbatim in the error message, and every other windows R installation I've ever seen would have a default libPath that looks more like "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library".

Comment: Ugh, if you're going to modify output like that you need to say so in the question clearly so we don't chase our tails based on wrong information! ;)

Comment: @joran sorry I should have been more explicit, just didn't want to post personal information :p